# If $S_a$ is finite and $b > a$ implies $S_b \subseteq S_a$, Does the set $S = \bigcup S_a$ has measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Let real number $a > 0$ and let $S_a \subset \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:

- $S_a$ is finite;
- If $b > a$, then $S_b \subseteq S_a$.

I am wondering whether the set $S = \bigcup_{a > 0} S_a$ has measure zero or not. It seems to me that $S$ might be uncountable in some cases, and it's obvious that each $S_a$ has measure $0$. But does the  union of all of the $S_a$ still has measure zero?

For the background, I am actually unfamiliar with the definition of Lebesgue Measure in general. I know the definition of a set in real number being "measure zero" is that it can be covered by countably many open intervals with the sum of their length being arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S=\bigcup_{a>0}S_a$ is actually countable. In fact, let $x\in S$. Then, there is some $a>0$ such that $x\in S_a$ and therefore, by considering some $q\in\Bbb Q\cap (0,a)$, there is some $q\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$ such that $x\in S_q$. Therefore $S\subseteq \bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q_{>0}}S_q$, which is union of countably many finite sets.